# How to send e-mail with PHPMailer with no SMTP Authentication?

Tags: php, email

I need to create a form in web where user asks for changes in his account of a government department where I work.

The PHP script should get this form and then send it to another department's e-mail address.

The TI department that deals with out infrastructure said that I can only use it's main smtp address to send e-mail, and the other would be blocked. So I can only use PHPMailer and not mail() function.

The problem is that our AD does not have a user / mail address be the sender of that e-mail. So How can I set PHPMailer to use that external SMTP address and no need of an account to send it? Is that even possible?

Comment: I always try to avoid sending programatically generated emails through a real local mail server for exactly this sort of reason. Using an HTTP based email service API like Mailgun will give you better results.

Comment: I can't change the current infrastructure. That's not my prerogative. This is not an opinion based forum :-(

Comment: There is absolutely no need to change any infrastructure. You'd simply be making connections to a web-based API.

Comment: @AlexHowansky as I said I just can't the Server admin won't let that server connect to Internet. The mail server which I will connect is local, and that is the one that has access to Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set `SMTPAuth` to be false:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host     = "host.yourdomain.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;

$mail->From     = "something@domain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Your Name";

$mail->AddAddress('you@you.com'); 

$mail->IsHTML(false);

$mail->Subject  =  'Subject line';

$mail->Body     =  'Email body';

$mail->Send();
```

Comment: I think OP is asking how to bypass the auth required by the local server. If you turn auth to false here, the server will (well, should) reject the message.

Comment: Erm... heh, if this solved the problem, then you have an insecure email server. :)

Comment: @AlexHowansky - not really. Depends on how the mail server is configured. For example, with Postfix you can specify `my_networks` and allow your servers to connect and "anonymously" relay mail w/o issue.  Better to do with auth, but not insecure.